# Tomcat can not open sjsxp-1.0.2.jar

Tags: maven, tomcat, jenkins, sjsxp

I have a maven project. And i am compiling intellij idea 13 without problems but i want to build in jenkins `/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/stream/sjsxp/1.0.2/sjsxp-1.0.2.jar; error in opening zip file`

this exception occur jenkins console. Anybody can help me ?
Thank you.

My maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream</groupId>
        <artifactId>sjsxp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That typically means that the jar file has somehow been corrupt. Try deleting /home/tomcat/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/stream/sjsxp/1.0.2/sjsxp-1.0.2.jar on the Jenkins-server and rerun the build.

Comment: Hi, i tried this suggestion.But can not solved problem :/ have you got another suggestion ? Thank you.

Comment: @cherry you can try to figure out if it really is corrupt. All jar-files are also zip-files, so you could try to unzip it. You could also have a look at the file size (or even better the sha1sum) to see if it is as expected: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/stream/sjsxp/1.0.2/

Comment: Yes, that was a cheksum exception. I downloaded sjsxp-1.0.2.jar, sjsxp-1.0.2.pom and copy to /home/tomcat/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/stream/sjsxp/1.0.2/ problem solved. But i don't understand why this problem occur when download maven's pom.xml that jars.

Comment: If your company uses a Maven proxy (like Sonar), the artifact might have become corrupt there. Then each time the Jenkins server downloads the artifact it gets the same corrupt version from the proxy.

Comment: Just glad I could help you:)